# error when creating table in hive

Tags: sql, hive

My query is

```
with subs2 as(
  Select columns
  from t1
  right join t2
  on conditions
)
CREATE TABLE new_n row format delimited fields terminated by '|' STORED AS RCFile AS
Select columns
from subs2
left join charge2
on conditions
where conditions;
```

The error I get looks like this

```
cannot recognize input near 'CREATE' 'TABLE' 'new_n' in statement.
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the `with` goes with the `select`.  So try this:

```
CREATE TABLE new_n row format delimited fields terminated by '|' STORED AS RCFile AS
    with subs2 as (
      Select columns
      from t1
      right join t2
      on conditions
    )
    Select columns
    from subs2 left join
          charge2
          on conditions
    where conditions;
```

Or, you can rewrite without the `with`:

```
CREATE TABLE new_n row format delimited fields terminated by '|' STORED AS RCFile AS
    Select columns
    from (Select columns
           from t2 left join  -- I much prefer `left join`
           t1
           on conditions
          ) subs2 left join
          charge2
          on conditions
    where conditions;
```